# Clickable LinearLayout inside ScrollView doesn't fire onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have the following problem. On my layout, I have a ScrollView with `fillViewport="true"`. Inside, I have a clickable LinearLayout (which in turn, has 4 views inside). It seems that my ScrollView intercepts the LinearLayout's onClick. My code is this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/signup_scrollview"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    ....
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">
        ....
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_product_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
         ....
         </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've tried to implement an `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`; on my ScrollView but to no avail. Can someone guide me as to how to fire my LinearLayout's onClick? Thanks.

Comment: try to put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on root layout.

Comment: Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to root layout hasn't worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this in inside linear layout tag

```
  android:onClick="onClick"
```

and inside your java code

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId()==R.id.add_product_button){
         // do your code here
         System.out.println("Layout click");
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, setting the onClick listener explicitly like this was the ONLY thing that worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have **disabled the click** in root tag, see `android:clickable="false"` in `<ScrollView>`, that's what doesn't let you make `LinearLayout` clickable.

Remove `android:clickable="false"` from `<ScrollView>`

Add `android:clickable="true"` to `LinearLayout`

and

`layout.setClickable(true);` in java file.

Comment: I still can't click my LinearLayout. I've tried setting true/false in clickable, focusable and focusableInTouchMode in the root element and no success.

Comment: @rion18  you don't need to write clickable or focusable anywhere, just write `android:clickable="true"` inside `LinearLayout` and also write `yourLayout.setClickable(true);` in your activity.java file

Comment: I've tried this and it hasn't worked. My ScrollView is still intercepting the click...